# how to join into a string a list of objects that can be converted to string?

Tags: python

i have a list of objects that do have a `__str__` method. and i want to get a string of all the objects in a list. but when i do the (obvious?) `' '.join(my_list)` i get an error `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, LogEntry found`

Btw, the goal of this is to simply feed a Tkinter Listbox content with log entries. If there are better ways to do that, let me know. but here is the code i have

```
class LogEntry():
  def __init__(self, msg, type):
     ...
  def __str__(self):
    return self.msg

my_log = [LogEntry("123", WARN), LogEntry("abc", DEBUG) ]

print "\n".join(my_log)
```

Comment: what should the output be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use list comprehension to make a list of `__str__`'s result on each object:

```
my_log_strs = [str(log) for log in my_log]
```

Or [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map):

```
my_log_strs = map(str, my_logs)
```

Now you can:

```
print "\n".join(my_log_strs)
```

Or more concisely:

```
print "\n".join(str(log) for log my_log)
```